# How to off prefix cyg for dynamic libraries in mingw64

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2

I use mingw64 in msys2
When build dynamic lib automatic add prefix cyg before target name.

How i can build libs wihtout prefix?

Comment: How exactly do you build libraries? And what libraries exactly? Maybe you somehow got Cygwin involved? I don't think MSYS2 uses this prefix for anything.

Comment: I agree with @HolyBlackCat. In MSYS2 shell `you can type `which gcc` to see which `gcc` is found first using the `PATH` environment variable. Chances are you have it pointing to a GCC under Cygwin instead of MSYS2.